join two table by closest date
I have 2 tables
apply_record

log_record

How can I left join apply_record to log_record on the right closest date.
for example
final


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use correlated subquery in the output list.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Could you please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle with your tables and data - this help eliminate errors and also eliminate duplication of work for those trying to help you.

One option is to find difference between apply and log date and rank rows by its absolute value. Then fetch rows that ranked as the highest.
For sample data:
SQL> with
  2  apply_record (id, apply_date, action) as
  3    (select 'B23', to_date('2024/05/02 10:38:36', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'buy'  from dual union all
  4     select 'C49', to_date('2024/05/01 10:00:36', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'send' from dual union all
  5     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/25 10:32:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'buy'  from dual union all
  6     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/04 10:38:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'buy'  from dual
  7    ),
  8  log_record (id, log_date) as
  9    (select 'B23', to_date('2024/05/02 10:38:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 10     select 'C49', to_date('2024/05/01 10:00:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 11     select 'C49', to_date('2024/04/29 10:55:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 12     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/29 10:44:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 13     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/25 10:33:47', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 14     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/25 10:22:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
 15     select 'G71', to_date('2024/04/04 10:11:37', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual
 16    ),

query looks like this:
 17  temp as
 18    (select a.id, a.apply_date, b.log_date, a.action,
 19       rank() over (partition by a.id, a.apply_date
 20                    order by abs(a.apply_date - b.log_date)) rnk
 21     from apply_record a join log_record b on a.id = b.id
 22    )
 23  select t.id, t.apply_date, t.log_date, t.action
 24  from temp t
 25  where t.rnk = 1;

ID  APPLY_DATE          LOG_DATE            ACTION
--- ------------------- ------------------- ------
B23 2024/05/02 10:38:36 2024/05/02 10:38:37 buy
C49 2024/05/01 10:00:36 2024/05/01 10:00:37 send
G71 2024/04/04 10:38:37 2024/04/04 10:11:37 buy
G71 2024/04/25 10:32:37 2024/04/25 10:33:47 buy

SQL>

